# Downloading pre-trained models from OpenVINO™ Toolkit Pre-Trained Models by Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: linux, openvino

I am trying to use some pre-trained model from the intel Pretrained model zoo. Here is the address of that site https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_models_intel_index.html. Is there any specific command for downloading these models in a Linux system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

downloader.py (model downloader) downloads model files from online sources and, if necessary, patches them to make them more usable with Model Optimizer;

**USAGE**
The basic usage is to run the script like this:

```
./downloader.py --all
```

This will download all models into a directory tree rooted in the current directory. To download into a different directory, use the -o/--output_dir option:

```
./downloader.py --all --output_dir my/download/directory
```

The --all option can be replaced with other filter options to download only a subset of models. See the "Shared options" section.

You may use --precisions flag to specify comma separated precisions of weights to be downloaded.

```
./downloader.py --name face-detection-retail-0004 --precisions FP16,INT8
```

By default, the script will attempt to download each file only once. You can use the --num_attempts option to change that and increase the robustness of the download process:

```
./downloader.py --all --num_attempts 5 # attempt each download five times
```

You can use the --cache_dir option to make the script use the specified directory as a cache. The script will place a copy of each downloaded file in the cache, or, if it is already there, retrieve it from the cache instead of downloading it again.

```
./downloader.py --all --cache_dir my/cache/directory
```

The cache format is intended to remain compatible in future Open Model Zoo versions, so you can use a cache to avoid redownloading most files when updating Open Model Zoo.

By default, the script outputs progress information as unstructured, human-readable text. If you want to consume progress information programmatically, use the --progress_format option:

```
./downloader.py --all --progress_format=json
```

When this option is set to json, the script's standard output is replaced by a machine-readable progress report, whose format is documented in the "JSON progress report format" section. This option does not affect errors and warnings, which will still be printed to the standard error stream in a human-readable format.

You can also set this option to text to explicitly request the default text format.

See the "Shared options" section for information on other options accepted by the script.

More details about model downloader can be found from the following url: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_tools_downloader_README.html

Comment: It is extremely helpful how OpenVino made it very much easy to download models. Thanks to the team who thought that not being able to download models from website would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the following url:-https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_models_intel_index.html, you can download the pretrained models using Model Downloader.(/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/downloader)

More details about model downloader can be found from the following url:
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_tools_downloader_README.html